# Find out which Grok filter rules are actually used

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have log data that is parsed by Logstash / Grok filter rules. Unfortunately, the structure of my log messages is not exactly well-documented, which leads to roughly 1000 filter rules. This makes the parsing process too slow for our purposes. However, I suspect that a very big majority of the data gets parsed by using only very few rules.

- How can I find out what rules are used how often?
- Or can I at least find out if any rules are not used at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to go there, you could add an `add_tag => [ 'filter42' ]` to your grok-filters. It'll let you figure out which filters are doing work, how many of them are, and give you hints as to which ones are doing nothing.